# Generate p2sh-segwit and address bech32

Tags: segregated-witness, p2sh, bech32-address

When I use `bitcoin-cli getnewaddress "" "p2sh-segwit"` which kind of script is inside And can I convert if in bech32?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Confusion about Addresses](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/95006/confusion-about-addresses)

Comment: You should never *ever* try to convert an address from one format into another, as you don't know what type the receiver software expects. If you want a particular type address, ask for it.

Comment: @MCCCS thanks. What kind of redeem script Can I have If I get p2sh? What is default script?

Comment: "legacy" will give you a P2PKH script. "bech32" will give you a P2WPKH script. "p2sh-segwit" will give you a P2SH-P2WPKH (a P2SH script with a P2WPKH redeemScript).